# use a list of lookup values to sort dataframe and return a timeseries of row values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, export-to-csv

I'd like to use a lookup table (a list of strings) to search a dataframe column(name) and return a timeseries of row values of other columns. The list of lookup strings will not exactly match the strings in the name column, but will contain similar strings (startswith?).

```
lookup=["AB","AC","AX"]

DF = name  year  mean  upper  lower
     AB2    2020   4     7      1
     AB_7   2021   5     9      2
     AC1    2022   3     9      2
     AX     2019   4     9      2
```

return:

AB.csv

```
2020  4  7 1
2021  5  9 2
```

AC.csv

```
2022 3  9  3
```

AX.csv

```
2019 4 9 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and the `regex` parameter with `rf'^{selector}'`. For each loop, this regex will keep only the rows (`axis=0`) for which the pattern matches the `selector` at the beginning of the string in the index column (`set_index('name')`).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
print(df)

lookup=["AB","AC","AX"]

df = df.set_index('name')
for selector in lookup:
    filtered_df = df.filter(regex=rf'^{selector}', axis=0)
    filtered_df.to_csv(f'{selector}.csv', index=False)
```

AB.csv

```py
year,mean,upper,lower
2020,4,7,1
2021,5,9,2
```

AC.csv

```py
year,mean,upper,lower
2022,3,9,2
```

AX.csv

```py
year,mean,upper,lower
2019,4,9,2
```